# Smooth projective curves of genus 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Is there a classification of smooth projective curves of genus $0$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

I know that if the curve has a rational point, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

The curve must embed as a degree $2$ curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$, so it has a point over some quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. This means the curve is a quadratic twist of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Doesn't Cassels say in his book on elliptic curves: "Fact. A genus 0 curve is equivalent to a line or conic"?

Comment: Your classification is correct. Are you asking for a stronger classification in some sense?

Comment: I would like a list of isomorphism classes of curves. I know each curve can be embedded as a conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$, but it isn't obvious (to me, at least) when two conics are isomorphic.

Comment: These kind of varieties are called Brauer-Severi varieties. The question is equivalent to asking for a classification of quadratic forms in three variables over $\mathbb{Q}$. I am not sure how useful is this for you.